# Why did I get an error by adding TextToSpeech?

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk, text-to-speech

I tried to intigrate a text to speech Funktion in my (Flutter) app, but if I write `flutter_tts: ^0.8.6` under `dependencies:`, how I saw it in a tutorial, I get an error.

That´s the Code in the `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
  flutter_tts: ^0.8.6

  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

and this is the error:

```
C:\Users\...\Desktop\tts_app\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library [:flutter_tts] C:\Users\...\Desktop\tts_app\build\flutter_tts\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 21,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.tundralabs.fluttertts" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library [:flutter_tts] C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\App Entwickeln\Projekte\tts_app\build\flutter_tts\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 21,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.tundralabs.fluttertts" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Where should I put the Code you sent me? @Srilal Sachintha

Answer (score 0):

TTS Plugin needs your android version to be greater than API Level 21.
but in the

> Android/app/build.gradle

file that value is still 16.
change it to 21 as following and you will be ok.

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.eventtweb"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

Comment: in the Android/app/build.gradle

Comment: @akashmaurya have you tried running `flutter clean` and then try again?

Comment: I solved my issue by dividing my text into groups of 4000 because tts doesn't support more than 4000 words. That is my issue

Comment: @akashmaurya please provide your complete code